# Remove vertical transformation from Matrix4

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to remove the vertical y axe from a translation Matrix?

I am using MatrixGestureDetector and would like to add constraints for vertical dragging a Transform widget:

```
onMatrixUpdate: (Matrix4 m, Matrix4 tm, Matrix4 sm, Matrix4 rm) {
            // remove y from tm?
            matrix = MatrixGestureDetector.compose(matrix, tm, sm, null);
```

Comment: https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/transform_demo2.dart#L90

Comment: My brain is exploding :-) You are the master, am I on the right track if I try to do something like this: Offset o = MatrixUtils.getAsTranslation(tm);
tm.setColumn(3, vector.Vector4(?,?,?,0));

Comment: yes, something like this: `Matrix4.translate()` (or `leftTranslate()`)